# Filling the entire content area with buttons in JQuery Mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating with JQuery Mobile a page containing a header, a content and a footer area. The entire content area must be split in two sections, 50% each, where each section must be a button, without any rounded corners or spacing, that can decrease or increase in size according to the device used and the layout of the device (portrait or landscape). I have tried several approaches, such as with `data-role="controlgroup"` and with `data-type="horizontal"` but it doesn't seem to provide what I want. Can someone tell me if it's possible in the first place and, if so, what elements and attributes should be used? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do this using `ui-grid` but you need to override JQM classes. I don't have my laptop now to give you a complete answer, but here is a little hint http://fiddle.jshell.net/pFqPF/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/TfzPw/

This solution requires:

1. jQuery Mobile grid (Omar mentioned it in his comment)

   ```
   <div class="ui-grid-a">
       <div class="ui-block-a"><a data-role="button" id="custom-btn">Button Left</a></div>
       <div class="ui-block-b"><a data-role="button" id="custom-btn">Button Right</a></div>
   </div><!-- /grid-a -->
   ```

   Official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids.html
2. Remove rounded corners:

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
       $('a').buttonMarkup({ corners: false });
   });
   ```

   Official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html
3. Remove padding on a content div:

   ```
   #index-content {
       padding: 0 !important;
   }
   ```
4. Remove button margines:

   ```
   #custom-btn {
       margin: 0 !important;
   }
   ```